# Exetending abstract method from superclass to sub class

Tags: java

I am looking over some old exam papers for an oop exam I have coming up one of them asks you to code a system where the super class is abstract and extends to 2 sub classes

```
abstract public class Employee {

private String name;
private String id;

public Employee (String name,String id){
       this.name = name;
       this.id = id;
}

public abstract float calculateMonthlyPay();

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public String getID(){
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
  return getID()+" "+getName()+" "+calculateMonthlyPay();
  }    
 }
```

All the code in the superclass Employee is fine but the paper asks you to then extend to a sub class PartTimeEmp and the monthly Pay method is to change from Float to Double 
When doing this java of course is giving errors as it says double is not compatible with float I cannot seem to find a way to make this work

```
public class PartTimeEmp extends Employee {

private double hourlyRate;
private int hoursPerWeek;

public PartTimeEmp(String name, String id) {
    super(name, id);
}

@Override
public double calculateMonthlyPay() {
    return 0;
   }

 }
```

Can this actually be made work ? Any help is appreciated

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.lang.Number` as your abstract method's return type.

Then you could return a new `java.lang.Float` or `java.lang.Double` in the overriding methods, since those types extend `Number`.

This technique is called [covariant return type](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java), and is possible starting from Java 5.

This requires you don't use primitives (which have no hierarchy), but their `Number` wrappers instead.

Note that for precise currency-related calculations it would be advisable to employ `java.math.BigDecimal`, rather than `float`s, `double`s or their wrappers - at least internally to the method and class instance's logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use type conversion technique without creating any overhead like:

`double x = (double) calculateMonthlyPay()`;